# How to connect Intermediate ssh server connection in PHP

Tags: php, ssh

How to connect linux server from PHP through intermediate server.

Local Machine(A) --> Intermediate Server (linux machine)(B) --> Linux Machine(C)

I want to connect A->B then B->C system. 
I have used below code.

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('121.2.3.11', 22); // 
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'username', 'id_dsa.pub', 'id_dsa'); // (B)  system connection

$tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, '121.2.3.12', 12345); // (C) system connection
```

Here, where to give username/password for C ("121.2.3.12") system.

Comment: You're authenticating via pubkey.. are you sure it's asking for a **password** after that or for a **passphrase** for the key? Are you sure that your pubkey is even valid for authenticating to that particular server?

Comment: For first system i have used username/password. Also i want to give username/password  for 2nd system

Comment: Good luck sorting your issue. Everything you need is on php.net, please give it a read.

Comment: there is no option to connect 2nd system with username/password

Comment: For clarity, you're trying to do something like `ProxyCommand ssh -q intermediate.example.com nc -q0 remote.example.com` (.ssh/config sample)?

Comment: yes i want this only

Answer (score 1):

You've [copied and pasted](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-tunnel.php) the example from the manual without apparently reading/understanding what ssh2_tunnel *does*.

You seem to be expecting that ssh2_tunnel creates an ssh connection - it doesn't. It creates a raw TCP socket connection which tunnelled through an existing ssh connection.

Do you actually have an ssh server listening on port 12345?

While there are *sometimes* good reasons for tunnelling an ssh connection inside an ssh connection, these are very unusual cases and there's no evidence that they apply here. If they don't apply, then ssh inside ssh is very innefficient and you should be relaying the connection instead. I'm not sure quite how you would do that as most ssh logins clear the input buffered, so you'd need to poll/respond to the prompt.

You've got no error checking in the code you've shown us. You should be checking the return values from each of the functions to check they were successful.

Comment: Here i entered sample code only. For security purpose, i haven't given original code. Simple thing is i want to connect linux machine C through PHP code. I can able to connect B machine. Is there any code example for this pls refer.